# Changing property type from string to integer in neo4j

Tags: windows, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get the movie recommendations using cosine similarity b/w users in my movie graph.

The cypher query is :

```
MATCH (p1:User)-[x:HAS_RATED]->(m:Movie)<-[y:HAS_RATED]-(p2:User)
WITH  SUM(x.rating * y.rating) AS xyDotProduct,
      SQRT(REDUCE(xDot = 0.0, a IN COLLECT(x.rating) | xDot + a^2)) AS xLength,
      SQRT(REDUCE(yDot = 0.0, b IN COLLECT(y.rating) | yDot + b^2)) AS yLength,
      p1, p2
MERGE (p1)-[s:SIMILARITY]-(p2)
SET   s.similarity = xyDotProduct / (xLength * yLength)
```

It throws the error:

```
Don't know how to Multiply(x.rating,y.rating) `4` with `4`
```

I thought that neo4j set the ratings to string instead of int, so I ran this query -

```
match (:User)-[r:HAS_RATED]->(:Movie)
with r limit 100000
set r.rating = toInt(r.rating) return r
```

But even after this update, I get the same error as I got before.

I know that I can add **toInt** modifier for each variable, but how do I multiply the rating field in my relationship without that, or in other words how do I set the rating as Integer?

Comment: I think your strategy here is correct. Reducing the complexity of the query I have been able to replicate the issue and indeed fix it by `SET r.rating = toInt(r.rating)`. Are you sure that all of your rating properties have been reset as integers? How many relationships have you got in your database? Your cypher uses `LIMIT 100000` - is it possible that you are not catching some of the relationships and so still have strings?

Comment: I have 1 million relationships. I thought the limit enforces on a single request, so the database wont run out of heap memory, but would ultimately run on the entire graph?

Comment: No. It will limit the results and hence only run on the 100000 you are matching. You would need to re-execute the query using `SKIP 100000 LIMIT 100000` until you have matched and hence reset all the rating properties.

Comment: Can it be packed in a single query? (without knowing in advance how many total relationships I have)

Comment: I must confess I am not sure...I don't know of a way to run the query in a loop. If you did not return `r` it would save some memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments above are pretty much on the right track. The best is to add a condition to skip those relationships that already have been converted:

```
match (:User)-[r:HAS_RATED]->(:Movie)
where r.rating = toString(r.rating) // make sure we only work string ratings
with r limit 100000
set r.rating = toInt(r.rating)
return count(r)
```

You run that statement until the returned value is 0 - that means there are no further relationships to process.

Comment: Good call on `where r.rating = toString(r.rating)`. +1. I think you might not be intending to have two `return` statements though!

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for query is as follows.
a small modification to @Stefan Armbruster code

```
match (:User)-[r:HAS_RATED]->(:Movie)
where r.rating = toString(r.rating) // make sure we only work string ratings
with r limit 100000
set r.rating = toInteger(r.rating)
return count(r)
```